# Can we link two controllers to a single custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I tried to find linking of multiple controllers to a single custom directive, but no solution. Is this possible to achieve or not. Can anybody please tell me.

Requirement: I created a directive with a controller. I'm calling that directive in a page and the page is having its own controller. Now the page controller have a couple of functions. I'm using a template with some events. Those events are implemented in the page controller (parent controller). So those functions are not firing.

```
<div ng-controller="controllername">
<myDirective name-"name" event="doSomeEvent(params)"/>
```

In the controller i have a couple of functions like

```
app.controller("controllername",['$scope','function($scope))
{
$scope.functionName = function()
{
alert(1);
}]
}
```

This function is linked to the directive template. How to make this event fired?

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that your directive has got an isolated scope.
meaning you have in your directive definition a line with scope: {}.
that makes it isolated and it can't see the parent scope (meaning that controller 'controllername' you have there)

remove the scope definition from the directive (remove the scope: {}) and you will have access to the parent scope.
and you will be able to use those function as if they were in the directive scope.

Comment: If i remove the scope , is this possible to manipulate with the properties that have been sent to the directive?
I added a controller to the directive already, will it works also?

Comment: No. But you can set that in the parent scope and child will see it

Comment: So set those flags in parent controller

Comment: In this, parent controller is "Controller1" and controller linked to directive is "Controller2", Will both going to execute is my question. Directive controller has lot of function to execute on the directive. It's not possible to remove.

Comment: yes, the directive will see both controllers if the directive is not using isolated scope (meaning no scope: {} defined in the directive). another way, is to put function in directive controller that will be called and it will call the parent controller via event ($scope.$emit('my event') and in parent $scope.$on('my event', function (event, ....)

Comment: It's not working. Parameters are not accepting when i set in the parent controller.

Comment: Correct, its not a directive, its a controller. Suggest you work with events like i wrotw before or make parent a direcrive as well (not recommanded)